# Адаптивный drupal 7?

Tags: drupal

Создаю сайт на Drupal 7, хотелось бы его сделать адаптивным, но так как я начинающий верстальшик, то у меня с эти проблемы.

Есть какие-нибудь ресурсы посвященные этой теме? может статьи или видеоуроки какие-то?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть видеокурс [Responsive Design with Drupal 
[Lynda.com]](http://www.lynda.com/Drupal-tutorials/Responsive-Design-Drupal/107419-2.html)

На просторах рунета можно скачать его бесплатно - поищите

На youtube есть много видео уроков и обзоров - просто введите в поиске на ютубе "drupal responsive"

Answer (score 0):

Возмите  какую-то популярную адаптивную тему
подсмотрите как  другие  сделали,
 бонусом  получите  всякие трюки и  плюшки которые делали  профи, а начинающий      может и  не знать.
  Измените ее  под себя.

Answer (score 0):

Очень хорошо документированный фреймворк для построения тем: https://www.drupal.org/project/zen , с помощью него легко можно научится делать хорошие темы, в том числе и адаптивные.